# Which Microsoft's Synchronization assemblies are required for device in reference?

Tags: synchronization, compact-framework, microsoft-sync-framework

I built app for device with Microsoft.Synchronization services for Ado.net.

I picked three assemblies:

Microsoft.Synchronization.Data
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe

from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\v1.0\Runtime\ADO.NET\V2.0\x86\
directory, however I get compilation error that one more assembly: Microsoft.Synchronization
is required ...

Is there device version of that library?

if I include it i get TypeLoadException error on device, which states that it cannot load System 2.0.0.0 on device...

Thanks for any hints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pick the one where it says Devices

e.g.,

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Synchronization Services\ADO.NET\v1.0\Devices